# ASLR Randomization and different regions

Tags: exploit, buffer-overflow

Essentially my question is, why ASLR doesn't randomize text, bss and data regions of the process? Also in the newer version of kernels (such as Linux kernel version 3.x) along with process base, libraries and stack addresses, are the heap addresses also randomized?

Comment: Really, I don't really know why its not clear enough. But okay Majority thinks, it ambigous.

Answer (score 3):

> why ASLR doesn't randomize text, bss and data regions of the process?

It does. The *base address* of the module is randomised, and therefore the virtual address of all sections will be randomised. However, the *relative* virtual address of sections from base must remain static, as most memory-access instructions work by relative offsets. Otherwise you'd need to generate fixups for every `mov` that crosses section boundaries (e.g. an instruction in `.text` that reads from `.data`).

It just wouldn't bring any real benefit, would cause lots of problems, and could be easily bypassed by reading known instructions in the current section (fixups are applied in memory).

> Also in the newer version of kernels (such as Linux kernel version 3.x) along with process base, libraries and stack addresses, are the heap addresses also randomized?

Yes. Each heap's virtual base address is random, and heap allocations are performed within that heap as normal.

Comment: Since the question is closed, so I cannot add any code snippet to explain what I mean. I have C code which has a global variable. So everytime when I execute the code, the base pointer changes as expected because of ASLR. But using gdb when I look at address of global variable, it always stays the same. As I know that uninitialized global and static variables are placed at BSS section, I assume the addresses to these parts are not randomized.

Plus referring to a paper here:
http://users.ece.cmu.edu/~dbrumley/courses/18732-f11/docs/aslr.pdf

Page 2, last para, says the same

Comment: The base address is randomized in Position Independent Executables (PIE), not old-fashioned executables. Note that gdb disables ASLR via `personality` by default.

Comment: You need `set disable-randomization off` to get meaningful results from `gdb`.